# Custom action SQL update not executing?

Tags: 7, entities, views, actions

I created a custom [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) action to change a value in the selected item. I have the button displayed as "hide item". When I activate it on the item it doesn't seem to fire and change the value at all. I did a test to change the name to xxxxx and visible to 0, but it doesn't look like its working. Maybe my code is wrong?

It does seem like its working as I output the result in the set_message function (**in green box in screenshot**). 1 indicates that 1 row has been affected, but i still see the item on my View and the name hasn't even changed.

Maybe something is off here?

**Module Code:**

```
function office_action_info() {
  return array(
    'action_off' => array(
      'type' => 'entity',
      'label' => t('Hide Item'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
      'triggers' => array('any'),
    ),
  );
}

function action_off($entity, $context = array()) {


$blah = db_update('office')
->fields(array(
    'verified' => 0,
    'name' => 'xxxxxxx',
))
->condition('office_id', $entity->office_id, '=')
->execute();


drupal_set_message($blah .'====='. $entity->name .'===='. $entity->office_id);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your structure of database table office? Can you show me pictures of it?

Comment: Also, please don't provide screenshot of code; code is simple text.

Comment: embeded code. and also gave a view of the database structure with sample data.

Comment: So since you're working with a custom `office` entity, perhaps it will have same problems with caching as `node`? Have you tried `entity_get_controller('office')->resetCache(array($entity->office_id));`

Comment: You could also try using the entity api in the `action_off` function. Simply `entity_load` then modify the values and then do `entity_save`.

Comment: yea thanks it seems to work now, but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to do an entity_save. there just aren't that many good examples out there for custom entities. I'm able to do a entity_load() and it displays.

Comment: @Beebee What is resetCache entity for? and why would those results be cached and when would I need to use this?

Comment: It's a default method for entities. Look [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3AresetCache/7)

Comment: @Beebee i currently have the entity resetCache line you provided before the entity_load and after entity_save. is that the correct way of using it? it seems that my code works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt fire. im guessing its this cache thing?

Comment: ok i see what the entity clearcache is for. so it clears the cache of just that node that just got saved? im assuming you put it after entity_save()?